# Is it possible to invoke "n" functions with same return type but with variable parameters using Func or Delegate in C#

Tags: c#, exception, delegates

Here is my scenario.
I have class with 10 methods, those methods are atomic, and are only 10 lines of code max.

So I was thinking, instead of handling the exceptions in each function, would it be possible, to create a delegate (? not sure its the right word here)

That so called wrapped function would execute those atomic functions and handle their exceptions, thus allowing me to centralize exception handling.

Is this possible in C# using delegate or Func, or maybe there is another way to centralize error handling that I might have missed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using one delegate to for several methods with different parameters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305295/using-one-delegate-to-for-several-methods-with-different-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible here is a code example

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Example {
        public void Run() {
            catchy(crashA); // Calling defined functions
            catchy(crashB);
            catchy(()=> {
                throw new ArgumentException("Anonymous function...");
            });
        }
        void crashA() {
            //...
            throw new ArgumentException("another error");
        }
        void crashB() {
            //...
            throw new ArgumentException("another error");
        }
        void catchy(Action action) {
            try {
                action();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            new Example().Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, with a delegate like this

```
private delegate MyReturnType MyDelegate(params Object[] a);
```

but it won't be type safe.

Comment: I like this method, I am curious if I could define a delegate of type <T>, this way 1 delegate could handle all my functions, (or maybe of type `object`

Comment: `public interface IProxy
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(Common.WcfFaultException))]
        string GetCurrentMode();

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(Common.WcfFaultException))]
        string[] GetAllChannels(bool lookInCurrentMode);

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(Common.WcfFaultException))]
        double GetChannelValue(string channelName);`
thats part of the interface.

Comment: @Elio: if that is really something we should read, put it in answer

Comment: @sehe, Its just a very typical interface, nothing special :), All answers are nice, but I liked the pattern mentioned Pranav.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would work for you, but you could possibly use the "Hole In The Middle" pattern or build an abstract class.

I was trying to do something similar where I wanted certain Pre and Post conditions to occur each time a given method was called.  In the same manner you could possibly put your Exception logic there instead of the Pre and Post conditons.  Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254881/using-hole-in-the-middle-pattern).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try the proposed solution there.

Comment: I came across this [http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/04/04/functional-c-the-hole-in-the-middle-pattern/](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/04/04/functional-c-the-hole-in-the-middle-pattern/), it is what you're mentioning, the technique looks nice and clean :)

Comment: @Elio Yes that is excatly what I am talking about. The link in my post gives a simple example on how I used it and how "SLaks" gave the technique of making it more generic so that parameters could be passed and returned.