# Should I invoke the delegate multiple times to pass different parameters to same method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method to do something based on the input parameter. Now, I want to call the method by adding to the invocation list of a delegate but with different parameters.

is it possible to do without invoking the delegate multiple times?

```
private delegate void myDel(int a);
private myDel del;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  del = delmethod;                
}
private void delmethod(int a)
{
 //Do something
}
private void call_methods()
{
 del(1);
 del(2); 
 del(3);
}
```

Is this the right way or I have any other options? Please note that , I may want to pass many parameters like this using a loop.

though I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305295/using-one-delegate-to-for-several-methods-with-different-parameters), they have solution only for calling different methods but I want for the same method.

**EDIT** :

> I want to transfer data from one
> database to another by calling the
> method depending on the parameter

Environment : Windows forms, .Net 3.5

Comment: I think you should state what you want to achieve more clearly.

Comment: I read it as: "How do I invoke a method multiple times without invoking it multiple times?". And that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I have updated my requirement, I want to transfer data from one database to other in that method by passing diff parameters

Comment: I read that update, but that didn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> by adding to the invocation list of a delegate but with different parameters.

Possible but ugly. You end up with something like:

```
del += (x) => delmethod(1);
del += (x) => delmethod(2);
del += (x) => delmethod(3);

del(-1); // Note the -1 is not used
```

Comment: are you adding the method to the invocation list? can you please explain how different it is from what I have done?

Comment: Actually I add a bunch of lambdas to `del`. Note that delMethod does not has to match  MyDel anymore.

Comment: can you please explain the advantage of transforming into lambda expression? thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
private void delmethod(params int[] abc)
{
  //Do something for each item in abc
} 

private void call_methods()
{
   del(1,2,3); //you can call with any number of parameters
}
```

Comment: im sorry not to explain clearly.I want to call the method each time with different parameters but not to pass array of parameters